# Apache Jena - Handle response code for model.read()

Tags: java, jena

I'm currently working with Jena to read rdf files. But my code sometimes return 403 Forbidden on line:

```
model.read(string, "");
```

How to handle if response code from that line is not 200? I already tried this way but it didn't work (since model.read(string, ""); is not a string)

```
URL url = new URL(model.read(string, ""));
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
int code = connection.getResponseCode();
```

my code:

```
Model modelTmp = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
modelTmp.read(string, "");

String queryString = 
"PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> " +
"select distinct ?rdr " +
"WHERE {?s dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects ?rdr }";
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
try (QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, modelTmp)) {
    ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect() ;}
```

Comment: Please post code as well

Comment: @AsthaSrivastava done

Comment: Catch org.apache.jena.atlas.web.HttpException. If you get a 403, the other end refused you access.

Comment: Ideally, use `RDFDataMgr` rather than `model.read`.